# Return count for last 7 days with missing days filled in

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying very hard to produce a dataset of total sales for each day in the last 7 days, with missing days filled in.

The result I'm looking for, for my example data, is:

```
2019-01-05  0
2019-01-06  0
2019-01-07  0
2019-01-08  0
2019-01-09  0
2019-01-10  1
2019-01-11  0
```

What I am getting is:

```
2019-01-05  0
2019-01-06  0
2019-01-07  0
2019-01-08  0
2019-01-09  0
2019-01-10  0
2019-01-11  0
```

The example data, albeit shortened for SO, looks like this, which is only one row:

```
id | saleID            | amount      | created
---|-------------------|-------------|-------------
1  | 6032b317-1533.... | 20000       | 2019-01-10 23:56:4

ID = INT 11 Auto
saleID = CHAR 36 INDEX
amount = INT 11 INDEX
created = DATETIME INDEX
```

My query looks like this at the moment:

```
SELECT
    qb.dy AS saleDay,
    COALESCE(COUNT(ets.saleID), 0) AS saleDayTotal
FROM eventTicketSales AS ets 
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT curdate() AS dy UNION
    SELECT DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS dy UNION
    SELECT DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) AS dy UNION
    SELECT DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AS dy UNION
    SELECT DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 4 DAY) AS dy UNION
    SELECT DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AS dy UNION
    SELECT DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 6 DAY) AS dy        
) AS qb ON ets.created = qb.dy AND ets.created > DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY qb.dy
ORDER BY qb.dy ASC;
```

You can [play with a fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88e734/11).

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong and suggest how it could be fixed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
... AS qb ON ets.created = qb.dy
```

You are comparing a datetime with a date without time. This does not match because the time is, obvisously, not the same.

To solve this you could convert the datetime to a date before comparing, using the `DATE` fuction :

```
... AS qb ON DATE(ets.created) = qb.dy
```

Comment: I can't believe that was all it was and I should have picked that up. It works now, so a big thank you!

Comment: Welcome @MartinJames !